# TypeScript duplicate function implementation issue

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm converting a project with a few javascript files to typescript files. Some of the function names are the same (although their implementations are different) e.g.

```
function covariateBlockEnableDisable() {...
```

exists in more than one .js/.ts file. As a result I get a "duplicate function implementation" error. I could rename the functions so that they are unique but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to how you are using these files. The reason you are getting this error is that all of those files are defined within the same scope (possibly on the window). There's no issue with this assuming you don't use all of the files in the same project, or you are using CommonJS/AMD. I'll go over both scenarios.

If only 1 of the files containing the `covariateBlockEnableDisable` will be included in a project, you need to compile them separately, or with the tsc flag `-m commonjs`.

If you are using CommonJS/AMD to import these files/functions, you will want to be using the tsc flag `-m commonjs` or `-m amd`.

If you are including all the files in a project and not using CommonJS/AMD then you have an issue anyway, since the methods will be overwritten.

Comment: I am using these files with 1 ts/js file per html page. In js this wasn't a problem as each js file had its own "scope", in ts it appears that scope is not per file but per module. As I wasn't specifying a module everything was considered to be in the same scope and hence the error. Now I have explicitly defined each ts file to be in a separate module and this has resolved the issue.